# How to pass configuration to AppDomain from Visual FoxPro application

Tags: dll, appdomain, visual-foxpro

I made COM visible .NET DLL in C# which refers an external DLL and the external  DLL reads app.config from current AppDomain. However my DLL is called from Visual FoxPro 9 so it misses content of app.config from my project.

Does Foxpro have something like app.config in .NET? I just need pass configuration to the external library via AppDomain from FoxPro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPF creates .exe file. Just create .exe.config file with the same content as dll.config.

Answer (score 0):

VFP doesn't have separate AppDomains like .Net. However, if you put your DLL in the same folder where your VFP executable is, then your AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is the folder where VFP executable is (IOW it is the same as VFP's justpath(Application.ServerName)). ie:

```
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "app.config");
```

Also App.config is just a plain xml file. You can read and process its contents as you wish from within VFP.

Comment: External library (which I don't have source code) is set to read .config file. My library nor VFP don't need read the .config file.

Comment: What do you mean? Your problem is not understandable.

Comment: I don't need process .config file in VFP or my dll library but the external library reads the .config file or key-values in AppDomain. I need to pass the configuration to the external library which I don't have source code to adjust it to read for example the current directory.

Comment: That is what I already said, please reread. If you put them into same folder then AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory is that folder.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the external library doesn't use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory. I was the first thing I tried.

Comment: What does it use?

Comment: It seems that current AppDomain